# Is an (n-1)-sphere quotient by an (n-1)-sphere contractible?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, homology

I am thinking about the homotopy type of the following quotient space:

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A$ be a subspace of $X$. If both $X$ and $A$ have homotopy type of a sphere $S^{n-1}$ (of the same dimension). Is it true that the quotient space $X/A$ is contractible? If not in general, will it be contractible under the condition $(X,A)$ is a "good" pair (e.g. simplicial pair)?

In fact, I am only looking at its homology and have tried to use excision and short exact sequence but in vain. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: No, consider a circle embedded in a cylinder that doesn't wrap around. This will be true e.g. if $A$ is a sub CW complex and the inclusion is a homotopy equivalence.